# Python I want to change the Working-Path outside the python program

Tags: python-3.x, cd

I need to change the Working-Path by Python just like using cd.
I have a shell (I am using windows so this is something like cmd or powershell)
and I want to change the shell's Working-Path by execute my python program.
or you can think I need a simple cd implementation in python.

I have tried the os.chdir(pathStr) and the os.system(cdCommand).
But they doesn't work.
It looks like a new shell is running in order to run my program and the new shell will exit when my program exit.The original shell change nothing.

Comment: Not possible; the current working directory is something that is passed from parent process to child process, never the opposite direction.  Note that `cd` is always a shell built-in command, it cannot be an external utility for this reason.